# Override System/AppDomain Events?

Tags: c#, delegates, signature

so i have been working on a bit of a POC
i want to be able to get lines of code from exceptions anywhere in the code when i have it compiled
so i am currently trying to see what i can do with

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

and i planned to do so with

```
[CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null
```

i already confirmed in the callstack it calls the delegated function directly but obviously the signature does not match this is the problem. i can't change the signature without changing the UnhandledException Type but i can't inherit AppDomain class (sealed) and i can't seem to think of any other ideas to get around this issue i am having

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    static class Program
    {

    public delegate void UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e, [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null);
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        UnhandledExceptionEventHandler c = Function_I_Want_To_Delegate;
    }

    static void Function_I_Want_To_Delegate(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e, [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
    {

    }
}
```

(More Info:)
[Photo of Entire Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60jYJ.png)

Comment: i pasted the code thanks for the tip will take note next time i thought i put the only 2 lines relevant but u can see it there now

Comment: Anybody got any suggestions ?